# Guard Not Recompiling Coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, bundler, guard, growl

I have a guardfile whose sole purpose is to recompile coffeescript files into js and sass files into css. So I created a Gemfile as:

```
source :rubygems

group :development do
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'guard-coffeescript'
  gem 'guard-sass'
  gem 'ruby_gntp'
end
```

and a Guardfile as:

```
group :development do
  guard :coffeescript, :all_on_start => true, :input => '.', :output => '.'
  guard :sass, :input => 'css', :output => 'css'
end
```

When I do `bundle exec guard`, I get this:

```
Guard uses GNTP to send notifications.
Guard is now watching at '/Users/sxross/Developer/Safari Extensions/iStockphoto/iStockphoto.safariextension'
Compile 
Successfully generated 
ERROR: Error sending notification with gntp: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

The sass is being successfully generated, but not the coffee script. I'm also wrestling with the GNTP issue. I'm running on Lion, and have the latest version of Growl and Growl Notifier. I just installed the ruby_gntp gem, so that should be current.

For background, this is a huge hammer designed to get around the fact that `coffee -wc foo.coffee` compiles initially, then compiles the first change, then never again does anything.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any error when you compile the CoffeeScript directly? Are you sure there's nothing missing from this output? The `Compile` line and `Successfully generated` lines look out of place.

Comment: No error compiling CoffeeScript. I'm already doing that. The `Compile` line and `Successfully generated` are from the CoffeeScript guard gem. In any case the sass in compiling. The output I supplied is complete. No errors other than the gntp one in evidence. What's strange is that even though it reports success, it doesn't actually do the compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to place your CoffeeScript files inside a directory in order for guard-coffeescript to work. You can't have the CoffeeScript files in the same directory as the Guardfile.

**Update:**

Did a little further investigation and noticed that if you place the input file regex inside the block instead of using the :input parameter, you can actually use CoffeeScript files in the current directory.

Change your `Guardfile` to something like this:

```
guard :coffeescript, :all_on_start => true, :output => '.' do
  watch(%r{(.+\.coffee)})
end
```

Comment: How strange. That does, indeed, work but '.' is a valid directory name -- odd that it would not work. Any thoughts about why the gntp error?

Comment: Do you have the latest Growl? I bought mine from the App Store and the gntp gem works for me, but that's about the only thing I can think of.

Comment: I updated my answer with a workaround for your situation. Now you don't have to place the CoffeeScript files in a separate directory.

Comment: I have the app-store version of Growl and just downloaded Growl Notify and installed gntp_ruby three days ago, so I think everything is in sync from a version perspective. Thanks for the addition to your answer.